# Characteristic function and cdf

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

How do we find the points of discontinuity of a distribution of a random variable if the characteristic function $\phi (t)$ is given?
How to find the cdf of a random variable X if the characteristic function is given by $$\phi (t)=\frac {1+e^{it}+2e^{2it}}{4}?$$

What is the relation between the characteristic function and cdf??

Answer (score 2):

As a consequence of Levy's Inversion Formula for characteristic functions, the jump of the cdf of $X$ at a point $b$ is given by
$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}{1\over 2T}\int_{-T}^T e^{-ibt}\phi_X(t)\,dt.
$$
Scrolldown some on this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulae).

You could use the inversion formula to find the cdf corresponding to the characterisitc function you cite. Or, reverse engineering the matter, observe that if a (discrete) random variable $X$ takes the values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with respective probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ ($\sum_{k=1}^np_k=1$, $p_k\ge 0$) then
the characteristic function of $X$ is given by
$$
\phi_X(t) =\sum_{k=1}^n p_k e^{ix_kt}.
$$

Comment: $P(X=0)=\frac {1}{4}$ $P(X=1)=\frac {1}{4}$ and $P(X=2)=\frac {1}{2}$ and rest $P(X=i)=0\,\,\,\, i\ne 0,1,2$, is this correct?

Comment: Indeed, it is..